# How do I wire a standard ceiling light to a ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm trying to attach a standard, 15 watt, ceiling light to the bottom of my ceiling fan using some of the instructions that were given on this website.

I've attached the blue and white wire coming out from the bottom of the fan to the black and white  wire in my new light. When I turn the wall switch on and even pull the drawstring on the fan to make sure it was going the light didn't turn on.

Does anybody have any idea why the light wouldn't come on?

---

Sorry if I was not clear. I figured most folks might know what i was doing from my explanation. The fan is about 10 yrs ago, so I no longer know the brand, nor have the  papers with it. It had a small 3 1/4" cap on the very bottom to remove for a ligth kit, but the kits available at Lowes etc. are huge or gaudy and no way work in a small kitchen, so I got a small round, 6" diameter very thin light that had just a black and white wire. The fan is rarely used but I presumed that attaching such a small, round light (albeit made for a ceiling) perfectly in the center wouldn't shake much at all. The fan runs smooth.

When the bottom cover on the ceiling fan was removed, there was many wires, but a neighbor who I felt knew what he was talking about said the unused blue is hot for a light and the white goes to my light's white wire. I attached the fan's blue wire to my light's black and then white to white, very solidly attached the light. There is only one wall switch for the fan so know I may have to accept a light on when the fan is on, too. The fan was put in by a builder over 10 yrs ago, so I don't know what wires he may/may not have left unattached. Hopefully you can give me some advice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What make and model is your fan?

Comment: Attach a "standard ceiling light" to a ceiling fan? That just doesn't sound like a good idea at all. The light fixtures that attach to ceiling fans are designed _specifically_ for ceiling fans - they've got mounting points designed to attach to the fans, and they're designed to put up with the vibration and motion of the fan. "Standard ceiling lights" are _not_ designed to do _either_ of these things. Please clarify what you're attaching to your fan.

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that attaching "random ceiling fixture" to a ceiling fan just isn't a good idea. Also, my ceiling fans have all required that I wire up both the fan & light in the ceiling before wiring up the light below the fan - you're probably missing the connection at the ceiling as noted in [Jim's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/245662/34147).

Comment: Hunter "schoolhouse" light kits are austere, not garish:  https://www.lowes.com/pdl/Hunter-5-5-in-x-10-5-in-Schoolhouse-White-Opal-Ceiling-Fan-Light-Shade-with-4-in-fitter/3470861?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-lit-_-ggl-_-PLA_LIT_227_Decor-Lighting-and-Ceiling-Fans-_-3470861-_-online-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAiAsYyRBhACEiwAkJFKopQ1XENfYRPl0yM9xnRkpCu7uUjd__BABBWloXodEtpFEdRjS0mVjxoCPWEQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Of course a small LED light fixture might work even if it was not designed for a fan. Is that what you have?

Answer (score 3):

The blue wire at the bottom of the fan must be connected at the ceiling to a hot wire of the house wiring (or a switched hot) in the ceiling box. Only then will the blue wire at the bottom of the fan be hot. If the fan was originally installed without a light kit, then possibly the installer left the blue wire unconnected to the house wiring.

The best arrangement is to have separate switched hots for the fan and the light, one will be black and the other red. One of these is connected at the ceiling to the black wire of the fan and the other to the blue wire for the light.

But if there is only a single wall switch and a single hot wire (usually it would be black),  then connect both the fan black and fan blue to this one black switched hot. There is a wall switch, right?

The white wire below the fan must also be connected to the neutral of the house wiring, but probably it is. In my experience there is only one neutral wire (white); it serves both the fan and the light.

Comment: I agree if no light kit was with the light it was probably not connected at the top.